# Where I should declare my amend identifiers?

Tags: ios

We are working on an iOS application and using amend cloud to perform various transformations on images stored by the user. Application is having number of views where we are pulling images from different different amend cloud subscriptions. How do I declare identifiers in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the amend_name as AmendName, access_key as AmendKey and access_secret as AmendSecret values under the Amend dictionary of the Info.plist.

[image]

source : http://amendcloud.com/docs/ios_integration